# How to merge lists of Map with Lists values using Java Streams API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I reduce the `Map<X, List<String>>` grouping by the X.p and join all the list values at the same time, so that I have `Map<Integer, List<String>>` at the end?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class X {
    int p;
    int q;
    public X(int p, int q) { this.p = p; this.q = q; }
}
Map<X, List<String>> x = new HashMap<>();
x.put(new X(123,5), Arrays.asList("A","B"));
x.put(new X(123,6), Arrays.asList("C","D"));
x.put(new X(124,7), Arrays.asList("E","F"));
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    entry -> entry.getKey().p, 
    mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, 
        reducing(new ArrayList<>(), (a, b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a; }))));
System.out.println("z="+z);
```

But the result is: z={123=[E, F, A, B, C, D], 124=[E, F, A, B, C, D]}.

I want to have z={123=[A, B, C, D], 124=[E, F]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `reducing` collector incorrectly. The first argument must be an *identity value* to the reduction operation. But you are modifying it by adding values to it, which perfectly explains the result: all values are added to the same `ArrayList` which is expected to be the invariant identity value.

What you want to do is a [*Mutable reduction*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) and [`Collectors.reducing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is not appropriate for that. You may create an appropriate collector using the method [`Collector.of(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(
    entry -> entry.getKey().p, Collector.of(
        ArrayList::new, (l,e)->l.addAll(e.getValue()), (a,b)->{a.addAll(b);return a;})));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it using two Stream pipelines :

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = 
// first process the entries of the original Map and produce a 
// Map<Integer,List<List<String>>>
    x.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().p, 
                                    mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                            toList())))
// then process the entries of the intermediate Map and produce a 
// Map<Integer,List<String>>
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect (toMap (Map.Entry::getKey,
                      e -> e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(List::stream)
                            .collect(toList())));
```

Java 9 is supposed to add a [flatMapping](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) Collector, that would make your life easier (I learned about this new feature thanks to Holger).

Output :

```
z={123=[A, B, C, D], 124=[E, F]}
```

Comment: Do you think it can't be done with a stream being collected by a single groupingBy or toMap (having some combination of mapping, reducing, flatMap...) in Java 8?

Comment: @tafit3 Currently I can't think of a way to do it in a single Stream pipeline.

Comment: It’s actually not that hard to do; there is only one mistake in the OP’s code…

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to achieve that in one run by writing your own Collector:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().p,
    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, 
      Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (a, b) -> a.addAll(b), (a, b) -> {
        a.addAll(b);
        return a;
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html) class of my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library such tasks can be solved quite easily:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = EntryStream.of(x)
           .mapKeys(k -> k.p)
           .flatMapValues(List::stream)
           .grouping();
```

Internally it's transformed to something like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey().p, e.getValue()))
        .<Entry<Integer, String>>flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), s)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
            Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

So it's actually a single stream pipeline.

If you don't want to use the third-party code, you can simplify the above version a little:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream()
        .<Entry<Integer, String>>flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey().p, s)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
                Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Though it still looks ugly.

Finally please note that in JDK9 there's new standard collector called [`flatMapping`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/ec06a1714c4d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l439) which can be implemented in the following way:

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
                               Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
            (r, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> result = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (result != null)
                        result.sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u));
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

Using this collector, your task can be solved simpler without additional libraries:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> z = x.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey().p, e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
                flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```