# How to create a map of maps from a list of maps with Java 8 streaming api

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

### Background

I have a list of maps that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "old": 0.25,
    "new": 0.3
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "old": 0.3,
    "new": 0.35
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "old": 0.75,
    "new": 0.7
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "old": 0.7,
    "new": 0.60
  }
]
```

and I want the output to look like this:

```
{
  "A": {
    "old": 1,
    "new": 1
  },
  "B": {
    "old": 1,
    "new": 0.95
  }
}
```

...where the values of `old` and `new` are summed for each related entry.

The data type of the list of maps is `List<Map<String, Object>>`, so the output should be a `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`.

### What I've Tried

With some diagram drawing, documentation reading, and trial and error, I was able to come up with this:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.get("name"),
            Collectors.summingDouble(entry ->
                Double.parseDouble(entry.get("old").toString())))
    );
```

to produce an object of type `Map<String, Double>`, where the output is

```
{
  "A": 1,
  "B": 1
}
```

for the summations of the `old` values. However, I can't quite transform it into a map of maps. Something like this:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.get("name"),
            Collectors.mapping(
                Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.get("old"),
                    Collectors.summingDouble(entry ->
                        Double.parseDouble(entry.get("old").toString())
                    )
                ),
                Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.get("new"),
                    Collectors.summingDouble(entry ->
                        Double.parseDouble(entry.get("new").toString())
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

doesn't work, because `Collectors.mapping()` only takes one mapping function and a downstream collector, but I'm not sure how to map two values at once.

Is there another function I need to create mappings of two different values? Any suggestions on better ways of doing this is greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: encapsulating `name`,`old` and `new` in a separate class could simplify your job, isn't it possible for you to extract it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use streams, but you can also use `Map`'s `computeIfAbsent` and `merge` methods:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
data.forEach(entry -> {
    String name = (String) entry.get("name");
    Map<String, Double> map = result.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new HashMap<>());
    map.merge("old", (Double) entry.get("old"), Double::sum);
    map.merge("new", (Double) entry.get("new"), Double::sum);
});
```

Comment: definitely more readable this way. btw one can even use the `toMap` collector but not soo readable without refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to achieve this only using `Stream` tools (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31650853/4105457)):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> collect = data.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(m -> (String)m.get("name"),
    Collector.of(LinkedHashMap::new,
        (acc, e) -> Stream.of("old", "new").forEach(key -> acc.merge(key, (Double) e.get(key), Double::sum)),
        (m1, m2) -> {
          m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, Double::sum));
          return m1;
        })
    ));
```

---

There is also the > Java 8 way:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> stats = data.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(m -> (String) m.get("name"),
        Collectors.flatMapping(m -> m.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !"name".equals(e.getKey())),
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (Double)e.getValue(), Double::sum, LinkedHashMap::new)
        )
    ));
```

Comment: this is actually pretty nice, 1+

Answer (score 4):

You are close to the solution with your first attempt, however you need to do some custom code to fully finish the picture.

You are going to need to implement your own [collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html), one transforms multiple Maps to a single double map.

This looks like:

```
       Collector.of(
            () -> new HashMap<>(),
            (Map<String, Double>target, Map<String, Object> source) -> {
                target.merge("old", (Double)source.get("old"), Double::sum);
                target.merge("new", (Double)source.get("new"), Double::sum);
            },
            (Map<String, Double> map1, Map<String, Double> map2) -> {
                map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, Double::sum));
                return map1;
            }
        )
```

This combined with your initial grouping by attempt solves the picture:

```
data.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.get("name"),
            // Insert collector here
        )
    );
```

Online full code example: http://tpcg.io/pJftrJ

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a class called `Pair`

```
public class Pair {
    private final double oldVal;
    private final double newVal;

    public Pair(double oldVal, double newVal) {
        super();
        this.oldVal = oldVal;
        this.newVal = newVal;
    }

    public double getOldVal() {
        return oldVal;
    }

    public double getNewVal() {
        return newVal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{oldVal=" + oldVal + ", newVal=" + newVal + "}";
    }

}
```

Then do it like so,

```
Map<Object, Pair> result = sourceMaps.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("name"),
                m -> new Pair((double) m.get("old"), (double) m.get("new")),
                (p1, p2) -> new Pair(p1.getOldVal() + p2.getOldVal(), p1.getNewVal() + p2.getNewVal())));
```

And here's the output,

```
{A={oldVal=1.0, newVal=1.0}, B={oldVal=1.0, newVal=0.95}}
```